# Change User Authentication in Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm running a procedure through openrowset to execute `select` in a procedure on another server, after a `DOMAIN` user has been deleted started to trigger the error below.

> *Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.*

Where can I set the other user?
For knowledge, I'm on one server and it's done linked server with server from another domain

my code

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'SERVER=xxx.xx.xx.xx;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;', 
    'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF ; EXEC [Z_ACOMPANHAMENTO_MAILING].[DBO].[USP_CHECKLIST_JOBS_DETALHADO] ''[DBM] ATUALIZAR_BLACKLIST''')
  AS A
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(D, DT_INICIO, GETDATE()) = 0;
```

Comment: [Object Explorer -> Server Objects - Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), but in your case the user comes from the current security context (your connection string uses Windows Authentication).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
There must be the same user and password in the other domain that is configured on the startup server.